# Web Audio HTML5 createMediaElementSource doesn't work the way intended? INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11

Tags: html, web-audio-api

I have a web audio project the needs to take an existing  tag on a page, grab it and play it through my web audio audio context.

```
<audio id="music" controls="true">
  <source src="DW2-AU01.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

Perhaps I'm making a mistake here, but loading the file into a buffer like this works:

```
var source = myAudioContext.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = myBuffers['FFA01.mp3'];
source.connect(myAudioContext.destination);
source.noteOn(0);
```

However, if I set it up with an  tag on the page and try to play the sound like this:

```
var source = myAudioContext.createMediaElementSource($('#music'));
source.connect(myAudioContext.destination);
source.noteOn(0);
```

I get INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11. I feel like I've exhausted my google searches, and the html5rocks examples that everyone posts has him creating the  tag in jQuery, not using one that already exists on the page.

Is this possible? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have seen this exception in other contexts being related to CORS and violation cross-domain rules

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I thought that too, as XSS won't allow me to XHTTPRequest it from my CDN. But this example is loading the same directory...

Comment: As an update to anyone reading that thread, using createMediaElementSource allows you pipe the audio through the API, but it's still controlled by the <audio> tag. So you can't use noteOn() to control it when created this way.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a jQuery reference. What if you try sending a reference to the native audio element?

```
var source = myAudioContext.createMediaElementSource($('#music')[0]);
```

Comment: I guess that's correct. I had tried that before, but was under the impression I would be able to do source.noteOn(0) and play the sound like it was loaded into my own buffer directly. It would appear that this technique only lets you feed the audio from the <audio> element to your filters/effects/etc in the web audio API, where what I needed to do was control it. That's unfortunate :/ (working with iOS and I want to play more than one sound at a time) Thanks for steering me correct though!